# Python Syntax Error in Hadoop Hortonwork Sandbox

Tags: python, hadoop

I am working on a word count task on Hadoop where I've uploaded a mapper and a reducer code. (These mapper and reducer codes work totally fine in Jupyter Notebook!)

However, when I run the reducer code on Hadoop, I am receiving a syntax error with regards to this line

```
Dictionary2 = {word:count for [word,count] in Dictionary1.items() if word.startswith('W')}
```

Here are my codes:

```
line 1: cd usr
line 2: cd tmp
line 3: hdfs dfs -get /user/text1.txt
line 4: hdfs dfs -get /user/*.py
line 5: cat text1.txt | python mapper.py | python reducer.py
```

The error msg I am getting:

```
Dictionary2 = {word:count for [word,count] in Dictionary1.items() if word.startswith('W')}

(Note: There is an upper arrow pointing under the word 'for')

**Syntax Error: Invalid syntax**
```

Does anyone know what the reason is? Is this due to the different Python versions of Jupyter and Hadoop?

Comment: Could you try: Dictionary2 = {word:count for word, count in Dictionary1. Items() if word.startswith(‘W’)}

Comment: Still got the same error... Thanks for the input though!

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: can you post your code snippet and the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: just posted my code. Sorry it looks a bit messy.

Comment: Likely causes: there's something like an unclosed parenthesis on the previous line - or you're using an absolutely *ancient* (pre-2.7) version of Python.

Comment: I ended up updating the my python syntax since the python version on Hadoop is 2.7